# pass parameters to constructor c#

Tags: .net, datagridview, constructor, eventhandler

Is it possible to pass parameters to a run-time-generated event handler? Here is where the event is created:

```
private void DataView_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip context = new ContextMenuStrip();
            int currentMouseOverRow = DataView.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
            int row = e.RowIndex;
            int column = e.ColumnIndex;
            if (currentMouseOverRow >= 0)
            {
                int rowsa = e.RowIndex + 1;
                int columnsa = e.ColumnIndex + 1;
                context.Items.Add("Add comment to row: " + rowsa + ", column: " + columnsa);
            }
            context.Show(DataView, new Point(e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex));
            context.ItemClicked += new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(context_ItemClicked);
        }
    }
```

My goal is to be able to fetch a value from an invisible dataGridView1 to its matching x and y co-ordinates of where the user clicks on the main DataView

```
public static void context_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        ToolStripItem item = e.ClickedItem;
        if (item.Text == "Add comment")
        {
            DataTable dt3 = frm.ds1.Tables[0];
            frm.DataView.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value = frm.dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Basically I need to replace the 'x' and 'y' with indexes
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
private ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler GetHandler(int x, int y)
{
    return (sender, e) => {
        Form1 frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        ToolStripItem item = e.ClickedItem;
        if (item.Text == "Add comment")
        {
            DataTable dt3 = frm.ds1.Tables[0];
            frm.DataView.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value = frm.dataGridView1.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

and use:

```
context.ItemClicked += GetHandler(42, 8);
```

?

Alternatively, you could use some state on the sender (typically the [`Tag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tag(v=vs.110).aspx)) to hold that state, and *fetch it out* from `sender`, i.e.

```
var yourState = (YourState)((Control)sender).Tag;
int x = yourState.X, y = yourState.Y;
```

Comment: Both solutions have helped here, and leaves for a lot more reading so thank you very much :)

Comment: Upon further inspection when trying to show a messagebox of a cell value from the parameters passed, no value is shown, just a blank messagebox. Could there be some oversight causing this? Thanks